# Lavaral 5 View syntax error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, syntax-error

Here is my error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\upload\index.blade.php)

Here is my index.blade.php

```
 <label>Uplod your Attachments</label>

{!! Form::open(array('url' =>'upload/uploadFiles','method' =>'POST','files'=> true)) !!}
{!! Form:file('images[]', array('multiple' =>true)) !!}

{!! Form::submit('submit', array('class' =>'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-4')) !!}

{!!Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: `Form::file`. You lost `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
{!! Form:file('images[]', array('multiple' =>true)) !!}
```

You wrote Form: instead of Form:: So you fix like this

```
{!! Form::file('images[]', array('multiple' =>true)) !!}
```

Comment: Dear sir not it gives this error..Class 'Form' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\upload\index.blade.php).can you please help me again.

Comment: Did you put : twice ? like Form::

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('url' =>'upload/uploadFiles','method' =>'POST','files'=> true)) !!}
{!! Form::file('images[]', array('multiple' =>true)) !!}

{!! Form::submit('submit', array('class' =>'btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-4')) !!}

{!!Form::close() !!}

Comment: Did you install Form like this ? `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"` and added to config/app.php aliases

Comment: Thank you very much sir,,um developing multiple uploading function..that`s why that error occurs..but now another error arrived.

Comment: ok cool. If I fix this error, please mark my answer first as the solution to this specific problem.